# Sorting a table with foreach?

Tags: php

Not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to sort a foreach table by a column, highest to lowest. The last column has a `count` formula to calculate `PilotData::getAllPilotsByHub` and I'd like the row with the highest number to be always first in the table.

```
<?php 
$allhubs = OperationsData::GetAllHubs();

foreach($allhubs as $hub)
{
?>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $hub->icao; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $hub->name; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo count(PilotData::getAllPilotsByHub(''.$hub->icao.'')); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your fetching it from databse, It is better to use ORDER BY and get the ordered data.

Answer (score 0):

its better if u get the data from the database in the sorted manner..

say

```
query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROm table ORDER BY column_1 ASC");
```

then use the foreach loop

since u need to order it, it can be more efficient if u fetch the data based on the ascending or descending order from the database...

Comment: Don't recommend `SELECT *`. It's almost always overkill.

Comment: Very rarely do you actually need to select **everything** from the DB, which is what `SELECT *` does. It's much better to only select what is needed.